# on $p^n+q^n=(p+q)^k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Evaluate the condition for integer solutions for $n$.

I found this question in an old book:

Find smallest number of form $2^n+3^n$ divisible by $625$. This solution is from that book; n must be odd and we may write:

$$2^n+3^n$$ $$=2^n+(-1)^n(2-5)^n$$ $$=2^n+(-1)^n\cdot 2^n-(-1)^n\cdot2^{n-1}\cdot5\cdot n+(-1)^n\cdot2^{n-2}\cdot5^2\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-(-1)^n\cdot2^{n-3}\cdot5^3\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}+625 N$$

$$2^n+3^n=5n\big[2^{n-1}-(n-1)2^{n-2}.5+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{3}2^{n-2}.5^2\big]+625 N;\ n\geq 4$$

The value inside box bracket is not divisible by $5$, so $n$ must be divisible by $125$ if $2^n+3^n$ must be divisible by $625$.

Similar reasoning can be used for any primes $p$ and $q$ such that:

$p^n+q^n≡0 \ mod (p+q)^k$

The condition is 
 $n=(p+q)^{k-1}$.

Now we try to apply Euler $\phi$ function:

$\phi(625)=625\big(1-\frac{1}{5}\big)=500$

$2^{500}≡1 \mod 625$

$3^{500}≡ 1 \ mod 625$

$3^{500}-2^{500}≡0 \mod 625$

$(3^{125}-2^{125})(3^{125}+2^{125})(3^{250}+2^{250})≡0 \mod 625$

Only $3^{125}+2^{125}$ can be divisible by 625. But $3^{125}+2^{125}$ can be factorized more and more.Suppose we can not use first method because p and q are too large, then how can we be sure the smaller factors are not divisible by $625$? is $n=125$ the smallest number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GENERAL PROOF

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes then $p,q,p,p+q$ are pairwise coprime.

We require $n$ to be odd and then $$\frac{p^n+q^n}{p+q}=p^{n-1}-qp^{n-2}+ ... +q^{n}\equiv np^{n-1}\pmod {p+q}$$
Therefore $p^n+q^n$ is divisible by $(p+q)^{k}$ if and only if $n$ is divisible by $(p+q)^{k-1}$.

Comment: My proof doesn’t work when $p+q$ is composite: I think this is a much better answer.

Comment: Thanks @URL. It's a similar idea to that used by Sophie Germain in her work on F.L.T.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, clearly, $$5\nmid 2^n+3^n.$$ For odd $n$, we can use [Lifting The Exponent](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/).

We have $$\nu_5\left(2^n+3^n\right)=\nu_5(2+3)+\nu_5(n),$$ so that $2^n+3^n$ is divisible by $625$ only when $n$ is divisible by $125$. That is, $\boxed{125}$ is the correct answer.